# What editions of Schopenhauer's principal works have translated quotations?

Tags: schopenhauer

I've got "The Fourfold Root" and "The World as Will and Representation", and I'm very much tempted to read them, however the untranslated quotations in Greek and Latin turn me completely off.

Any quotes in other languages could be easily translated, however, these languages...

It is also important to notice that I usually read on my Kindle, since I live in Brazil and in reason of the populace's general distaste for anything of an even mildly intellectual nature plus the government's extortion makes it either very difficult to find such material in print, or it's rather too costly for an average man to buy them, or both. So, I'd prefer one that's easily found as an ebook.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try [here](http://gen.lib.rus.ec/search.php?&req=schopenhauer+will+dover&phrase=1&view=simple&column=def&sort=extension&sortmode=DESC).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I found Cambridge's Fourfold Root, in which all notes are present. 
I'll check the other later.
Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EFJ Payne's translation of 'The World as Will and Representation' translates in footnotes all the foreign language quotes. This is available in a Dover Books edition.

More generally all your quotational problems are solved in The Cambridge Edition of the Works of Schopenhauer : https://www.cambridge.org/core/series/cambridge-edition-of-the-works-of-schopenhauer/B170AEEEFD3EDA48A6B95CA334C996D2

Comment: @Ezequiel Barbosa. You have an answer to your question.

Comment: I think Payne's will do. Buying Cambridge's is, as I said, way too expensive for me.

Thanks.